# How to automate colorbar adjustment in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, spatial, colorbar, colormap

I am ploting a spatial map in MATLAB. The data I have has few large values.

When I create the color bar it ranges from 0 to 80, but the majority of values are between 0 to 20.

Below is the histogram of values 
[image]

How to modify the colorbar in MATLAB to show color division to show a separate color division for values >20

Required color bar divisions :  `[0, 4, 12, 16, 20, >20]`

The default way divides the colors into equal division and the variation gets lost as larger part of color division goes for values between 20 to 70.

I can do it manually like `caxis([0,20])` but is there any way to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do:

```
% Assume your data is stored in x & y
b = bar(x,y,'FaceColor','flat');
thresholds = 0:4:20;
colours = {'r';'b';'g';'y';'c'}; % for example
for k = 1:length(thresholds)
    b(x>thresholds(k),:).CData = colours{k};
end
```

I haven't tested it, not having your data but hopefully should work.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should automatically set the upper limit for the colorbar at a point where around 80% of the points are lower than that value (80% can be changed, and how close the value is to 80% depends on the number of bins used)

Data is assumed to be in a variable `data`

```
[n,edges] = histcounts(data,'Normalization','cumcount');
limit = edges(find(n/length(data)>0.8,1)+1); %change 0.8 here to preferred fraction
caxis([0,limit])
```

Comment: It seems to work but there is a issue with color scale. Many time last value in the upper end of color scale stops at say value=9, but in actual case there are many values > 9, in this case the color bar gives a misleading information. Is there any way to create a triangle kind of thing in the color bar (https://matplotlib.org/_images/colorbar_only.png) like this, so that reader can have some idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot an unequal spread of data, you can scale/normalize values to a range of [0,1].

```
range = max(data) - min(data);
data = (data - min(data)) / range;
```

if you want to scale to any given range of [x,y], first normalize to [0, 1] and then:

```
range2 = y - x;
data = (dataa * range2) + x;
```

**Putting it all together:**

```
function normalized = normalize_var(array, x, y)

 % Normalize to [0, 1]:
 m = min(array);
 range = max(array) - m;
 array = (array - m) / range;

 % Then scale to [x,y]:
 range2 = y - x;
 normalized = (array*range2) + x;
```